# Is it possible to use % Memory utilization for Azure scale set autoscale setting?

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I have an Azure VM Scaleset on Windows VMs, and I am trying to setup an autoscale rule that would increase the number of instances if the Memory utilization gets over a certain threshold. There's an option for Percentage CPU, but not RAM. Tried creating the autoscale rule through Terraform since I saw it in some documentation somewhere, but got an error saying "MetricUnsupported". Is this really not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Azure VMSS does not support using `CPU Utilization` in autoscaling rules. It just support `CPU Credits Consumed` or `CPU Credits Remaining`. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsoftcomputevirtualmachinescalesets)

[image]

Comment: VMSS does support "Percentage CPU", which is in the doc and is what I meant to say. I updated my original post. This does not answer the question though.

Comment: @JohnRamos We can use the `Percentage CPU` to do that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZZRQ.png.